# How to access WebApi using "http"?

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api

Now I created a WebApi and set its project url to `https://localhost:44332/`.

I can access it using url `https://localhost:44332/api/test/get`. But I also want to use `http` to access it, just like `http://localhost:44332/api/test/get`.

[image]

How do I configure the WebApi?

Answer (score 1):

Environment for local machine development can be set in the `Properties\launchSettings.json` file of the project.

If you launch your project with IISExpress you could setup which ports to use for `https://` and `http://` like this

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59481",
      "sslPort": 44308
    }
  },
```

In this case, the application will be available on `http://localhost:59481` and with SSL on `https://localhost:44308`. Please note that both endpoints could not have the same port (even in public web HTTP and HTTPS are on different ports, usually 80 and 443)

You could read more about the setup of the local environment [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0)